# How to recieve data from SPCI commands in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have implemented the following code for controlling my spectrum analizer shown bellow.

I cant understand how to properly store a responce from my device.
for example there is the simple *idn? command which returns the model.
how do store properly the responce.
i Have tried to use serialPort1.ReadTo but its description(shown bellow is not very informative.
How do i store string responce from my spectrum analizer in C#
Thanks.

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        bool meter_state = false;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Open();
            serialPort1.Write("meas:freq:st 500 mhz\n");
            serialPort1.ReadTo
            serialPort1.Close();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ReadTo reads data until it finds the specified value

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readto?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

If you know that the response from the serial ends with a specific string (like a newline character) I think you can do something like

`string data = serialPort1.ReadTo("\n")`

You can also read data from the serial using Read (but you need to know the length of the data to read or check for the ending string by yourself) or, better, use the DataReceived event

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialdatareceivedeventhandler?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Something like

```
serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(OnDataReceived);


private void OnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string data = sp.ReadExisting();
}
```

Comment: Hello Paolo,I want to read a data which comes as responce to my write command, serialPort1.Write("(*idn?\n");
how do i catch the sended data which cmes as a responce to my command? Thanks.